# Display:inline-block not centering vertically in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

Although everything works in other browsers, the sort by item found in the top right corner is not centering vertically in Google Chrome(latest version). Cannot really figure out why the hell that is happening. If I reduce the width it works otherwise no.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Very weird thing in Chrome:
If you are using display inline block, you need to specify vertical-align:top otherwise it will go to baseline, which is the default. Even if you have a line-height which usually works, Chrome ignores it.